# How to implement "Interlocked Compare exchange if less"?

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, multiprocessing

I have a piece of old legacy code that does:

```
if (current_Value > g_max_Value) g_max_Value=current_Value
```

As you understand with all modern super multi-threading, multi-cpu and huge CPU cache, this code does not work well.
Question: How write it reliably, but elegant?

Quick solution is to wrap it in critical section. But if I understand correctly this does not guaranty atomic on CPU level.

Comment: Use compiler builtins, if applicable. We can't tell you more since you haven't even specified the architecture, or the compiler, for that matter.

Comment: Jester, thank you for attention. I'm interested particularly in x86 and x64

Comment: Just write a standard CAS loop. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Modern C as of C11 has atomic data types, for which you can use `atomic_compare_exchange_strong`, e.g.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence? Of course a critical section, a mutex, will be atomic.

Comment: @2501: Protecting it with a lock/critical section is not *quite* the same as making it atomic. You can't use locking for things that could be accessed in a signal handler.

Comment: In windows you can use InterlockedExchange api

Comment: @JensGustedt: I think we actually need a retry-loop to implement a compare for less than instead of for equal, so we should just use `atomic_compare_exchange_weak`.

Comment: @Jester: ISO C11 provides atomics, so we don't need anything compiler or architecture specific.  This is fine as a pure C question.

Answer (score 2):

If multiple threads could possibly be *updating* `g_max_Value` at the same time, you need an atomic cmpxchg.

If not, then you don't, even if other threads could be reading it while one thread writes it.  You might still need to ensure the stores and loads are atomic, but you don't need an expensive atomic read-modify-write if only one thread is ever writing it at the same time.

If you have any requirements on the order in which updates become visible to other threads, then you also need [release / acquire memory ordering](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) or something like that.  If not, then "relaxed" memory ordering will ensure that operations are atomic, but won't waste instructions on memory barriers or stop the optimizer reordering at compile time.

---

**ISO C11 already provides [atomic compare-exchange](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange) as part of the language**.  Of course, it's an exchange-if-equal because that's what hardware typically provides, so you'll need a loop to retry.

**The basic idea is to do the compare for greater-than, then use an atomic cmpxchg for the swap, so the swap only happens if the global hasn't changed (so the compare result is still valid).**  If it has changed since the compare-for-greater, retry.

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

atomic_int g_max_Value;

// if (current_Value > g_max_Value) g_max_Value=current_Value
bool update_gmaxval(int cur)
{
    int tmpg = atomic_load_explicit(&g_max_Value, memory_order_relaxed);
    if (cur <= tmpg)
        return false;

    // global value may change here but still be less than cur, so we need a loop insted of just a single cmpxchg_strong

    while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
             &g_max_Value, &tmpg, cur,
             memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed))
    {
        if (cur <= tmpg)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

We could simplify by changing to a `do{}while()` loop:

```
// if (current_Value > g_max_Value) g_max_Value=current_Value
bool update_gmaxval_v2(int cur)
{
    int tmpg = atomic_load_explicit(&g_max_Value, memory_order_relaxed);

    // global value may change here but still be less than cur, so we need a loop insted of just a single cmpxchg_strong

    do {
        if (cur <= tmpg)
            return false;
    } while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
             &g_max_Value, &tmpg, cur,
             memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed));
    return true;
}
```

This compiles to different code, but I'm not sure it's better.

---

#### We get more efficient code if we don't return a true/false:

I put the code up on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOBDDB7AWxAgDoALAPgChRJZFVM4AjPPKc6q3Q4gfXAYkAcz4FsADz4A1bLAQBuKlQD0KpCABmSABQQYAJwMIwGGXJjIKIsZPPyAlDfFTZ8gLz6jJs28tVWdiQYAAccDAQ%2BYRcANzkdQSQvByoAbyokTI1TJAwCEOEkdyQeIgg%2BKDxsOD4ECRCoYhAMHQAyURd7SwAaJAIEAjwDAE8%2BIcQDPmMoSQQ4ByUsjW09Q1RivIKUpaXjDEMwJE05NEVlJbURSuY5JDj5PuxhpLJsMGFkMgRjJGYYIUwICgUF%2ByCgCDQaFyr0OXl6aDwSAA7sgwAg5iUkJU8CFspgMXhtAArGCYTFocDCcFJfISCBkUSYAx4d7nLJIshA5A6ACEpX4EEIIWwxlqdJhHz4KOwAGsxQ0mi0MjsVUh2rZXBYEL1WpthL04crVUt%2BoMRmMDBMpggZhI5r1TUNRuNvtbbXMHNssuljVpdF51rl8sIvcbMnsDkcTmclgBfI1ICMGQ4YAyWJTx5SXACCEH2cigzw%2BaIMuAhSDgWk03x8STwDAwMOhyE0IAMZJi3wpLJIqnUftW3lMXSszjsfgQTg6461nkMxmHE4CbBBoXCkWiknufBiACYEjlkmkE4k9UUSvgyhUqjU6gqIM02tPNfIHQMnRardNZvMlAnLlSeA3CC9yWI8zz0m8HxIF8Px/ACGBAiCzBghCUKNm8SSGPCiIokgaIYtgWJsLi4D4nASCEkgJJkkRFLvNSEC0vSjKpiywhspkcCIj6qoDgGKAbMGoZhkmhzHFApyLFksbIpy1K8vy5SCvkIqRHUkHvJE0pynejQPkqYZLOqnQTjqeoGthCZho65oupM352nAb5ms6lquo5HoLAmYm5GmZyZn2ajBSFoVqFm6h4R8QhmsgCCaK2D61oKDB%2Bnh3FgAA5EIrydrkiLFt8ZaYr5oEIBFzanL8eCNnW%2BRcs2SBoNg/RUDEeAgBRa5llEsRyDuHVwAeQjJEgqTBGEPWbhI9yDgsSDxu1nUTeuvVbv1e4DZ1w1YQYTjjd1ERrTNG37skCgLVQQAAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) to see if it compiled and look at the asm.  Unfortunately Godbolt's ARM/ARM64/PPC compilers are too old (gcc 4.8), and don't support C11 stdatomic, so I could only look at the x86 asm where it doesn't matter that I used `memory_order_relaxed` instead of `memory_order_seq_cst` (`lock`ed instructions are already full memory barriers, and normal loads are implicitly acquire-loads).

I did notice that these wrappers compile to significantly tighter code

```
void update_gmaxval_void(int cur) { update_gmaxval(cur); }
void update_gmaxval_v2_void(int cur) { update_gmaxval_v2(cur); }
```

because they don't have to return a value.

Comment: gcc 4.8 doesn't provide `stdatomic`s (without defining `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__`, no less), but it *does* support effectively the same functionality and API with the `__atomic*` builtins. If you replace `atomic_load_explicit()` with `__atomic_load_n()` and `atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit()` with `__atomic_compare_exchange_n()` you should be able to test the ARM/POWER versions.

Comment: @EOF: interesting, thanks.  I'll keep that in mind for sometime when I actually care :P  I was only mildly curious this time, and I expect it's just the usual LDREX/STREX load-linked / store-conditional.

Comment: @EOF: dammit, I wasn't curious until your comment made me think more about it.  I have a more recent ARM gcc cross-compiler installed locally.  The key part of the loop is: get the expected value into r1, then `ldrex   r3, [r2]` / `cmp     r3, r1` / `strexeq lr, r0, [r2]` / `cmpeq lr, #0` / `bne   .L41`.  So it uses a predicated `strex`.  That's funky :P

Comment: @Downvoter: which part of my answer is wrong or in need of improvement?  It's not my greatest piece of writing ever, and a bit rambling, but I'm fairly confident the function I posted will work correctly.  I didn't write functions for the versions that don't need an atomic cmpxchg, because there are too many possibilities.